# What does "akhdaan" mean?

Tags: tafseer, arabic

What does أَخْدَانٍ (used in verse 4:25 and 5:5) mean?

> ...مُحْصِنِينَ غَيْرَ مُسَافِحِينَ وَلَا مُتَّخِذِي أَخْدَانٍ...

I have checked a few tafseers like [Al Tabari](http://quran.ksu.edu.sa/index.php#aya=5_5), Ibn Kathir, and Al-Mizan but still not sure about the meaning.

Since illicit sexual relations seems to have been stated 
previously and separately as مُسَافِحِينَ 
does أَخْدَانٍ refer to nonsexual/nonphysical relations, 
i.e. close friends or platonic lovers?

I have also seen some translate this as "*secret* lovers" or "*secret* (male) friends". 
Is "secret" implied by the word? Is it synonym with الصَّديق في السِّر or الصَّديق? Or does it mean a friend so close that one shares secrets with?

Answer (score 2):

> غير مسافحات ولا متخذات أخدان

The word خدن means friend, but in the Ayah it means a women taking a secret lover, or having sexual relationship with one man, where مسافحات  is where a women goes and has sexual relations with any man.   Also it might be said that مسافحات are those women who have sexual relations and make it public, while متخذات **أخدان** are those women who have sexual relations in secret.

For more information see [Tafseer Al Qurtubi](http://library.islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?flag=1&bk_no=48&surano=4&ayano=25)

Comment: I'd like to add this link http://www.almaany.com/ar/dict/ar-en/%D8%B9%D9%82%D9%84%D9%8A/home.php?word=%D8%A3%D8%AE%D8%AF%D8%A7%D9%86&lang_name=ar-en&type_word=0&dspl=0